# Convert A String to Unix Date format

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a String stored as a Label in this format : 2014, 8, 01, 0, 0, 0. This is eventually meant to return a UNIX_TIME_STAMP. So I tried the following :

```
private static final String myDate = System.Label.My_Date;
Long dt = Datetime.valueOf(myDate).getTime();
System.debug('The specified date = ' + dt);
```

But I get error 'Invalid Date/Time'. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse . The date you are trying to convert is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue :

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse(System.Label.My_Date);
Long x = (Long)Datetime.valueOf(dt).getTime();
System.debug('The specified date = ' + x);
```